# python code with list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}

tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total=sum(numbers)
    avg=float(total)/len(numbers)
    return avg
students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]
def get_average(student):
    for a in student:
        homework=average(a["homework"])
        quizzes=average(a["quizzes"])
        tests=average(a["tests"])
        student= .1 * homework + .3 * quizzes + .6 * tests
    return student

print get_average(students)
```

The code above  only outputs the average for one student Tyler,the last one from this list `students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]`.

However i think this list doesn't work but Codecademy did use this list in their lesson.
I want print the average of all three student..please help..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are only using the last value of `student`, you need to append all the student values throughout each iteration if you want to see them all:

```
def get_average(students):
    students_avs = []
    for a in students:
        homework = average(a["homework"])
        quizzes = average(a["quizzes"])
        tests = average(a["tests"])
        student= .1 * homework + .3 * quizzes + .6 * tests
        students_avs.append(student) # append each result
    return students_avs
```

Output:

```
In [13]: get_average(students)
Out[13]: [80.55, 91.14999999999999, 79.9]
```

`student= .1 * homework + .3 * quizzes + .6 * tests` points to a new value each iteration so logically you only see the last value calculated for the final student as you never save the value each iteration in your own code.

You could also return a list comprehension:

```
def get_average(students):
    return [.1 * average(a["homework"]) + .3 * average(a["quizzes"]) + .6 * average(a["tests"])
            for a in students]
```

Another option would be to use `get_average` for a single student and call the function in a list comp:

```
def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    student = .1 * homework + .3 * quizzes + .6 * tests
    return student


out = [get_average(d) for d in students]
print(out)
```